# Subgroup with Finite Index of Multiplicative Group of Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory

Let $F$ be an infinite field such that $F^*$ is a torsion group. We know that $F^*$ is an Abelian group. So every subgroup of $F^*$ is a normal subgroup.

My question:

Does $F^*$ have a proper subgroup with finite index?

Comment: What is $F^*$? It can mean many things.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva $F^*$ is a multiplicative group of field $F$.

Comment: You mean the group $F^{\times} = F \backslash \{0\}$ with multiplication? I've never seen the notation $F^*$ before so I asked. Thanks

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, I think that's a rather pretty standard notation in most books I remember.

Comment: @Don : I guess we just didn't use the same books then!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $F$ be the algebraic closure of a finite field. Each element of $F^*$ belongs to a finite field, so is a torsion element. On the other hand $F^*$ cannot have a subgroup of index $n>1$. For if $A$ is such a subgroup, then $x^n\in A$ for all $x\in F^*$. But if $z\in F^*\setminus A$, then $z$ has an $n$th root in $F^*$ contradicting the previous sentence.

---

Returning to the general case. If $F^*$ is torsion, then obviously $F$ has finite characteristic, and is algebraic over its prime field. Therefore $F$ is contained in an algebraic closure of a finite field. If $F$ itself is finite, then it obviously has finite index subgroups, but this was excluded by the OP.

---

And as an example of an infinite field such that $F^*$ has a subgroup of a finite index let's try the following. Consider the nested union of extensions of $\mathbb{F}_2$ of degrees $2^n$ 
$$
F=\bigcup_{n\ge0}\mathbb{F}_{2^{2^n}}.
$$
The union can be formed inside an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_2$.
For $m\ge n$ let $N^m_n:\mathbb{F}_{2^{2^m}}\to\mathbb{F}_{2^{2^n}}$
be the relative norm map.
 For $n\ge1$ define the groups
$$
A_n=\{z\in\mathbb{F}_{2^{2^n}}\mid N^n_1(z)=1\}\le \mathbb{F}_{2^{2^n}}^*.
$$
Transitivity of norm in a tower of field extensions means that
$N^n_1\circ N^m_n=N^m_1$ for all $1\le n\le m$.

Let us define
$$
A=\bigcup_{n\ge1}A_n.
$$
I claim that $A$ is a subgroup of $F^*$. It is obviously closed under inverses, as all the $A_n$ are groups as kernels of $N^n_1$. If $z\in A_n$ and $n<m$, then
$$
N^m_1(z)=N^n_1(N^m_n(z)).
$$
Here $N^m_n(z)=z^{2^{m-n}}$ is just a power of $z$, so we get that also $z\in A_m$. We have seen that $A_n\le A_m$, and the claim follows from this.

To close off this example I claim that $A$ is of index three in $F^*$. Let 
$\mathbb{F}_4^*=\{1,\omega,\omega^2=1+\omega\}$, where $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity. Because $N^n_1(\omega)=\omega^{2^{n-1}}$ is either $\omega$ or $\omega^2$, it follows that for every element $z\in F^*$ exactly one of $z,\omega z,\omega^2 z$ belongs to the subgroup $A$. The claim follows from this.

Note that the argument from the case of an algebraically closed field does not apply for this $F$. For example, the field $F$ does not have ninth roots of unity because those reside in the field $\mathbb{F}_{64}$, and won't be included in this tower.

Comment: What do you mean by "If F itself is finite, then it obviously has finite index subgroups"

Comment: Well, the index of the trivial subgroup in the whole group is finite, say...:)

Comment: @Babgen: That was an exaggeration in the sense that there may not be non-trivial subgroups. If $2^m-1$ is a (Mersenne) prime, then $F^*$ has no non-trivial subgroups. Other than those and the field of three elements the multiplicative group of a finite field always has non-trivial subgroups.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This uses the very same reasoning as Jyrki's answer but with a different, perhaps slightly more groupwise,  approach:

(1) An abelian group $\,A\,$ (with multiplicative operation, to fit within our problem) is *divisible* if

$$\forall\,g\in G\;\wedge\;\forall n\in\Bbb N\;\exists\, x\in G\;\;s.t.\;\;g=x^n$$

(2) Any homomorphic image of a divisible group is divisible.

(3) Finite abelian groups can **not** be divisible

(4) Divisible groups cannot have finite-index subgroups (this is just (2)+(3))

(5) The multiplicative group of an algebraically closed group is abelian

Now apply Jyrki's answer...